# Do I need anything else besides a keycloak token to access a service secured with keycloak?

Tags: java, rest, http, token, keycloak

I can get a valid token from keycloak, but I still get a 404 not found response from a service secured with keycloak when I try to access it with the token. What else do I have to do? What else is needed to access a service secured with keycloak?

I am getting a bearer token back.

I created the simplest service I could and deployed it as a WAR onto Wildfly. I installed the keycloak adapter into wildfly and added a keycloak.json file to the war along with modifying the web.xml.

For the web.xml I added the information from the documentation:

```
<module-name>application</module-name>

<security-constraint>
 <web-resource-collection>
   <web-resource-name>Resources</web-resource-name>
   <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
 </web-resource-collection>
 <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
 </auth-constraint>
 <user-data-constraint>
   <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
 </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
<auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
</login-config>

<security-role>
  <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

I added the user role to keycloak

I have a client program that takes a user and password and gets a token back from a keycloak installation

```
 AuthzClient authzClient = AuthzClient.create();            
 AccessTokenResponse response = authzClient.obtainAccessToken(name, password);

 String tokenStr = response.getToken();
```

I then try to use that token to make a REST call to the WAR secured with keycloak:

```
  String urlString = "http://localhost:8080/simple-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/resources/message";
  URL url = new URL(urlString); 
  HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  con.setRequestMethod("GET");
  String authString = "Bearer " + tokenStr;
  con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authString);
  basicStatus = con.getResponseCode();
```

basicStatus returns the 404. Am I just using keycloak wrong here? Am I missing something?

Comment: you should get a 501 unauthorised if keycloak is not working.  404 means page not found.  are you sure the page is there?  also, can you provide a little more information, like which container you are using (TomEE, Wildfly, etc) and how you have set up keycloak (e.g. dropping the support jar into TomEE)

Comment: I added more information into the post.

Comment: if you remove the security-constraint can you access the endpoint or do you still get a 404?  if you look at my gist here https://gist.github.com/chongma/bc97c30ba1fdcce9d059a506bccba0dc this is how i get an access token from keycloak client.  i use cxf webclient to return a KeycloakToken object.  i have included the KeycloakToken object as an example.  the access_token is the bit you need to use as the bearer token.  i am not sure you can use the token that you have there because i feel like i tried that before.  but maybe you can...

Comment: Removing the security-constraint from web.xml has no effect. I still get a 404.

Comment: try using a rest client to test connection to your rest endpoint before adding the security layer. i use ARC (advanced rest client) as a chrome plugin.  with TomEE as the server starts it lists your endpoints and their locations so you can see where they are deployed.  not sure about wildfly

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, getting 404s all over (strange initially because my browser could verify the endpoint, but none of my code/curl/postman).

In my case, I thought I was getting the bearer token, but the String that I was actually getting was something else.  The bearer token should be lengthy (and can be verified/compared via other methods).

To do a postman call for the token:

Do a POST to: `<host>/auth/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/token` 

Add header Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

In the body, select x-www-form-urlencoded and be sure to include:

- grant_type
- client_id
- username
- password

The code that I was running was retrieving the session_state (much shorter and not the bearer token like I thought it was retrieving).  For some reason, when supplying an improper bearer token (even an expired token), all my endpoints resolved 404 (instead of any other remotely helpful code).